# How to pass coordinates to Google Places iOS API

Tags: ios, google-places-api

I'm using Google Places in one of my apps where given coordinates, I need to find nearby places. Places' iOS API can either use [current place](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/current-place) or you can use [place picker](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/placepicker). I don't want either of these but to pass coordinates and get nearby places as I'm getting these coordinates from an image.

Answer (score 0):

**This will return you nearby places by  passing coordinates . Just call this function and pass your coordinates**

```
func getPlacesUsingCoordinates(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, radius: Double, name : String){

    //Pass name of place you want to search nearby in name

    var urlString = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=\(apiServerKey)&location=\(coordinate.latitude),\(coordinate.longitude)&radius=\(radius)&rankby=prominence&sensor=true"
    urlString += "&name=\(name)"
    urlString = urlString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

    placesTask = session.dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: urlString)!) {data, response, error in

        if let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:nil, error:nil) as? NSDictionary {

            if let results = json["results"] as? NSArray {

                    if let name = results["name"] as? String {
                       print(name) //Place Name 
                    }
                    if let location = results["geometry"] 
                       print(location) //Geometry
                    }

            }
        }
        self.placesTask.resume()
      }
    }
```

If you want further place details use :

```
CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(yourLocation) { (placeDetails, error) in
     // This provide every info related to location. Just pass yourLocation here       
}
```

**Hope this is what you are looking out for.**

Comment: Appreciate your effort but I'd need to parse and further query for selected place's details with another web call. However, it's the only possible option for now.

Comment: You don't need any further WS Call. It will return all the response, you simply need to parse it

Comment: @MayaReo Yes you need to do a geometry reverse request to get all address components.

Answer (score 0):

When Cinema pass that place you should get type like restaurant,bars etc

**Swift**

```
func fetchPlacesNearCoordinate(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, radius: Double, name : String){
            let apiServerKey = "API-Key"
            let urlString :URLRequest = URLRequest.init(url: URL.init(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=\(apiServerKey)&location=\(currentlatitude),\(currentlongitude)&radius=\(radius)&types=\(Cinema)&rankby=prominence&sensor=true&name=\(Cinemas)")!)

            print(urlString)
            UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true

            let placesTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlString) {data, response, err in guard let data = data, err == nil else{
                print("error ==>\(err)")
                return
                }

                let responsestring = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
                do {
                    let jsondata1 = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSDictionary
                    print("Final data Convert to JSON =>\(jsondata1)")

                    let results = jsondata1["results"] as! NSArray
                    print("Results ==> \(results)")
                }
                catch{
                    print("error ==>\(err)")
                }

            }
            placesTask.resume()

        }
```